# strange text in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have app name show's in my `CoordinatorLayout` but i want to remove it , so were to find that text or view , my `XML` file doesn't have this text view

[image]

XML file code :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

it should use

```
app:titleEnabled="false"
```

in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findviewbyid(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(null);
```